# How can I change all the names in a list to one in R?

Tags: r, lapply, gsub

How can I change all names like: Finland:Aland Islands:Foglo into only: Finland? I tried using
lapply(gsub , pattern = "Finland*", replace = "Finland") But it won't work.

I would also do the same with other countries, like Germany, Denmark.. e.t.c.
And also, is there a way to order these countries alphabetically in a list?

Thank you in advance

```
1        Finland:Aland Islands:Foglo
2       Finland:Aland Islands:Eckero
3  Finland:Aland Islands:Fasta Aland
4                            Austria
5                            Belgium
6                           Bulgaria
7                        Switzerland
8             Cyprus:Northern Cyprus
9                             Cyprus
10                    Czech Republic
11                    Germany:Usedom
12                   Germany:Fehmarn
13                     Germany:Rugen
14                         Germany:4
15                           Germany
16                         Germany:6
17                   Denmark:Lolland
18                         Denmark:2
19                       Denmark:Mon
20                       Denmark:Als
21                 Denmark:Langeland
22                  Denmark:Bornholm
23                       Denmark:Fyn
24                         Denmark:8
25                     Denmark:Samso
26                 Denmark:Sjaelland
27                     Denmark:Laeso
28                           Denmark
29                  Spain:Formentera
30                       Spain:Ibiza
31                     Spain:Majorca
32                     Spain:Minorca
33                             Spain
34                  Estonia:Saaremaa
35                      Estonia:Muhu
36                   Estonia:Hiiumaa
37                           Estonia
38                         Finland:1
39                         Finland:2
40                         Finland:3
41                         Finland:4
42                         Finland:5
43                 Finland:Vallgrund
44                  Finland:Halluoto
45                           Finland
46                    France:Corsica
47               France:Ile d'Oleron
48                            France
49                  UK:Isle of Wight
50                 UK:Wales:Anglesey
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gsub` is vectorized so you don't need `lapply` (unless you are wanting to apply the function to multiple columns). In regex, `*` is a quantifier indicating 0 or more of the thing that comes before it, so the pattern `"Finland*"` matches `"Finlan"` followed by any number of `d`s.

Instead, let's replace the first `:` and anything after it `.*` with an empty string. (`.` in regex means "any character", so `.*` is "any number of any characters".)

```
gsub(pattern = ":.*", replacement = "", x = your_data$your_column)
```

> And also, is there a way to order these countries alphabetically in a list?

I'm going to mostly ignore this as a separate question for a few reasons

1. It's not clear what you mean -- do you really want a `list` class result??. Do you want to include duplicates? Are there other columns that need to stay with the corresponding rows?
2. It's not clear you've tried anything. Have a look at  `?sort` and `?order` or maybe just the FAQ on [How to sort a data frame?].
3. It's unrelated to the main question, and it's bad practice to combine unrelated questions.

Have a look at the resources I mention, have a try, and if you're still having trouble ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
test<-c("Finland:Aland Islands:Foglo","Germany","Finland:Aland Islands:Eckero")
test<-sort(gsub(":.*","",test))
```